# Given an offset in an extracted combined text string, how to determine containing node and offset?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Given the following HTML (just an example):

```
<div id="container"><span>This is <strong>SOME</strong> great example, <span style="color: #f00">Fred!</span></span></div>
```

One can extract the text using e.g. jQuery's `text()` function:

```
var text = $('container').text();
```

Now, what would be the simplest, fastest, most elegant way to determine that the offset `10` in the extracted text corresponds to the offset `2` of the text node inside the `<strong>SOME</strong>` node in the example above? Also, how would one do the inverse, i.e. determining the offset `10`in the extracted text from the `<strong>`DOM object and the offset `2`?

Comment: What about the whitespace preceding the `span` ?

Comment: Sorry, malformed example. Removed the whitespace.

Comment: Support all major vendors (IE/FF/Safari/Chrome/Opera), but it is safe to assume a recent, HTML5-compliant-ish release (that would be something like 9/4/5/12?/11?, respectively).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a start. You can use TreeWalker to get a pretty elegant solution. You need to implement `TreeWalker` for IE (assuming you need IE support) though.

```
function findOffset(node, initialOffset) {
  var offset = initialOffset;
  var walker = node.ownerDocument.createTreeWalker(node, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT);
  while(walker.nextNode()) {
    var text  = walker.currentNode.nodeValue;
    if (text.length > offset) {
      return { node: walker.currentNode.parentNode, offset: offset };
    }
    offset -= text.length;
  }
  return { node: node, offset: initialOffset };
}
```

[demo](http://jsbin.com/axowoz/2/edit)

Now for the reverse...

Comment: Seems to work! For the sake of answer completeness, IE 9 has TreeWalker, which is good enough for me with regards to IE support.